# Конструкция else if

Tags: c

```
#include

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

main()
{
    int c, n1, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    n1 = nw = nc = state = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        +nc;
        if (c == ‘\n’)
            +n1;
        if (c == ’ ’ || c == ‘\n’ || c == ‘\t’)
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }

    }
    printf(“%d %d %d\n”, n1, nw, nc);
}
```

Это задача подсчитывает слова. Пример взят из книги Керинагана и Ричи. Я понимаю почему переменная state устанавливается в состояние вне слова ,когда находит: пробел, знак табуляции или знак перехода на следующую строку. Но совершенно не понимаю вот этого момента кода

```
else if (state == OUT){
    state = IN;
    ++nw.
}
```

Правильно ли я думаю, что это конструкция нам говорит, что противном случае если это не пробел, не табуляция, не знак переноса, то мы в слове и счетчик слов должен накручиваться?

Но в справочнике написано, что конструкция else if выполняется если правильно if, то есть (state=OUT). Но как может быть правдой то, что мы вне слово и одновременно запускаться параметр на то, что мы в слове IN. Помогите, пожалуйста, я уже голову сломал.

Comment: @proxyarp, хотя @gecube IMHO все объяснил, попробую чуть по другому.

    Правильно ли я думаю, что это конструкция нам говорит, что противном случае если это не пробел, не табуляция, не знак переноса, то мы в слове и счетчик слов должен накручиваться?

Нет, если мы "в слове", то состояние == IN и в этот блок мы не попадаем. 

Т.е. он срабатывает только когда заканчивается очередная последовательность разделителей. 

Для простоты мы *не различаем первый разделитель от остальных* в последовательности, каждый раз для разделителя устанавливаем состояние в OUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так все очень просто. Этот код реализует автомат с различными состояниями. Состояние OUT - это когда мы ВНЕ слова, IN - внутри слова. Переход IN->OUT происходит при нахождении символа разделитея (' ','\n' и '\t'). Переход OUT->IN при нахождении любого другого символа, только если лишь мы были ВНЕ слова. Иначе мы продолжаем дальше идти по символам слова.

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь это Вам поможет.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN  1 // состояние "в слове"
#define OUT 0 // состояние "вне слова"

main()
{
    int c, n1, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    n1 = nw = nc = state = 0;

    // Пока не достигнут конец
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        // берем следующий символ
        ++nc; // ОБЩЕЕ количество символов

        // если он перевод строки
        if (c == '\n') {
            // запоминаем кол-во переводов строки
            ++n1;
        }

        // если символ пробел или перевод строки, или табуляция
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            // переводим состояние в "вне слова"
            state = OUT;
        } else {
            // иначе если состояние вне слова
            if (state == OUT) {
                // переключаемся на "в слове"
                state = IN;
                // и записываем кол-во начал слов
                ++nw;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n", n1, nw, nc);
}
```

Comment: Тут с `return'ами` намного все очевиднее было бы, имхо.